# Property 'concatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'?

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I upgraded from Angular 4 to 5 and replaced `Http` with `HttpClient`.  I removed chained map from my `http.post` call which now returns an `Observable<Object>`, but in my component it is now complaining that `concatMap does not exist on type Observable<Object>`.  Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
//service
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

registerDomain()
{

return this._http.post('/api/domain/domain/register', {});
}

//component
registerDomain(caseId,domain) {
    return this._domainService.registerDomain(caseId,domain)
      .concatMap(operation => this.getOperationDetail(operation.OperationId,this.caseId,domain))
      .concatMap(() => this.createRecordSets(domain));
  }
```

I can see map and mergeMap on `Observable<Object>` but not `concatMap`

Comment: Have you imported the necessary extras?

Comment: I did the following: import {concatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Please give a [mcve], then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try importing this:

`import 'rxjs/add/operator/concatMap'`

Comment: This works but what about the new syntax for importing?

Comment: You can use the destructuring here as well: 

import {concatMap} from 'rxjs/add/operator'

The difference is 'rxjs/add/operator' which adds an instance method to instances of Observable vs. 'rxjs/operator' which adds a static method to Observable

Comment: `import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';` for **angular 6**

Answer (score 5):

You need use pipe

```
registerDomain(caseId,domain) {
    return this._domainService.registerDomain(caseId,domain)
      .pipe(
         concatMap(operation => this.getOperationDetail(operation.OperationId,this.caseId,domain))
         concatMap(() => this.createRecordSets(domain))
    );
  }
```

Comment: This works as well, but why do do I only have to do it with concatMap and not something like mergeMap or flatMap?

Comment: I think you need do this for mergeMap and for flatMap as well! Or maybe you import concatMap and flatMap from rxjs/add/operator!

Comment: There's no need for the `.` in `.concatMap()`.